# parity json RPC eth_getBalance timeout on light mode

Tags: parity, json-rpc, balances

I have timeout problem with `eth_getBalance` on light mode enable on parity `json-rpc`. I have no problem with light mode disabled.
Here my command on parity

> parity --chain ropsten --jsonrpc-apis all --jsonrpc-cors all --pruning
>   fast --db-compaction ssd --cache-size 1024 --mode active --warp
>   --light

is there any way to fix it ?
I am running on Mac OS.

Comment: I'd check if you have connectivity issues with your network, perhaps you do not have enough peers.